# How to download images from link using python

Tags: javascript, python, beautifulsoup, request

I trying to Download images from 
link = https://mahabhunakasha.mahabhumi.gov.in/bhunaksha/27/index.jsp

I using beautifulsoup for that, I get the all html but the village image link i couldn't find to download.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import ssl

ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context#

for dist_name in ['Akola', 'Amravati', 'Buldana', 'yavatmal', 'washim', 'Aurangabad', 'Beed', 'Jalna', 'Osmanabad', 'Latur',
                  'Nanded', 'Parbhani', 'Hingoli', 'Mumbai City', 'Mumbai Sub-Urban', 'Thane', 'Palghar', 'Raigad', 'Ratnagiri',
                  'Sindhudurg', 'Bhandara', 'Chandrapur', 'Gadchiroli', 'Gondia', 'Nagpur', 'Wardha', 'Ahmednagar', 'Dhule', 'Jalgaon',
                  'Nandurbar', 'Nashik', 'Kolhapur', 'Pune', 'Sangli', 'Satara', 'Solapur']:
    # print('-- {} --'.format(dist_name))
    # r = requests.get('http://igrmaharashtra.gov.in/eASR/eASRCommon.aspx?hDistName={}'.format(dist_name))
    r = requests.get("https://mahabhunakasha.mahabhumi.gov.in/bhunaksha/27/index.jsp")
    # print(r.url)
    for i in r.url:
        if r.status_code == 200:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
            select_list = soup.find_all('select')

            for select in select_list:
                # print('Select name: ' + select.attrs['name'])
                option_list = select.find_all('option')
                text = [option.text for option in option_list if option.text]
                print(text)
```

**Edit:**
If u click that link then the mention web page will be display, so i want to download that map image from all area mention in left side of page.
[After u click that image:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KNHg.png)

the encoded link is in inspect->source->js/jquery/js.
want to download all map images(.png) and store on local.
thanks in advance...

Comment: Where are you using the `dist_name` inside your code. As far as I can see, it's in `comments` section only.

Comment: link doesn't works - at least I get error. If you have links in js then read it. It is plain text so you can use string functions or regex to get links.

Comment: @ Sukumar Rdjf:- Initially i use that but i just want to extract that all names from web. so it will made dynamic.

Comment: @furas: Please see edit section and Guide me please

Comment: I'm also getting an error. Please post the whole `r.text`.